# React onDoubleClick handler is not called

Tags: reactjs

How to handle the *dblclick* event in React? The docs lists [onDoubleClick](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events). However the following code does not fire any events when double clicking on the img.

```
<img src="blub.jpg" onDoubleClick={ () => console.log('Im not fired') } />
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/0xw944vjvl its working for me.Could you please check console?

Comment: Just confirming, the above codebox that RIYAJ posted works for me too (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: The above code works on Desktop. I was trying to fire the event on an emulated mobile device. Which unfortunately is not a dblclick event... Ty guys for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

some how onDoubleClick works when your browser dev tool is closed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Even though this could probably be added as a comment, it seemed to be the issue for me. When I closed the devTools, the onDoubleClick fired.

Comment: Just saw this issue in Chrome browser (Version 120.0.6099.216 (Official Build) (arm64))